# Как обработать KeyboardButton.WithRequestContact в Telegram bot'е?

Tags: c#, telegram

Мне нужен бот, который будет просить поделиться номером с ботом, а бот отправлял информацию мне по API telegram. Вопрос: Как например вывести инфу в консоль? Console.WriteLine(Инфа), Инфа не message.Text ... Как вывести данные в Console?

Так выглядит код, который просит пройти "Капчу", т.е. поделиться номером:

```
        ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboardMarkup = new(new[]
        {
            KeyboardButton.WithRequestContact("\u2705Я человек"),
        });

        await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(id, "Подтвердите, что вы человек кнопкой ниже.",
            replyMarkup: replyKeyboardMarkup);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: следующее сообщение которое вы получите из текущего чата от пользователя будет отправленным контактом, если пользователь согласится его отправить

Comment: Как мне его вывести в консоль? Это не Message.Text (Console.WriteLine(message.Text) не будет работать)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Я нашел ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: нужно в начале проверить сообщение на наличее контакта

```
if (message.Contact is not null)
{
//Что то делаете
}
```